# Flyway and Spring Boot integration

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, flyway

I trying to integrate Flyway for migrations in a Spring Boot project with Hibernate and Spring JPA. I'm getting the following Exception:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'flyway' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/flyway/FlywayAutoConfiguration$FlywayConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.flywaydb.core.api.FlywayException: Found non-empty schema "PUBLIC" without metadata table! Use init() or set initOnMigrate to true to initialize the metadata table.
```

My `pom.xml` is looking like this:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
  <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
  <version>3.2</version>
</dependency>
```

I'm using Hibernate and a config java file for postgres (dev stage) and h2 (local). The signatures are looking like this:

```
  @Bean(initMethod = "migrate")
  public Flyway flyway() {
    Flyway fly = new Flyway();
    fly.clean();
    fly.init();
    //flyway.setInitOnMigrate(true);
    fly.setSchemas("SBA_DIALOG");
    //flyway.setLocations("filesystem:src/main/resources/db/migration");
    fly.setDataSource(this.dataSource());
    fly.migrate();
    return fly;
  }
@Bean(name = "sbaEntityManagerFactory") @DependsOn("flyway")
  public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
...
```

I can't find anything about my problem described in this question. 
Can anybody help?

Comment: Spring Boot already supports flyway the only thing you need is add flyway as a dependency... I suggest a read of the [manual](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-database-initialization.html#howto-execute-flyway-database-migrations-on-startup) and for the [configuration properties](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html). For me it looks like you are using boot and try very hard to work around it (explicitly configuring everything for instance).

Comment: quite strange: spring boot should not start flyway autoconfiguration if you configure flyway for yourself (question is if it is necessary). however error comes from boot autoconfiguration. however try to add `flyway.initOnMigrate= true` to your application.properties and remove your own flyway initialization :)

Comment: @sodik Actually I've flyway in classpath (3.2.1) and it does not work. What may be the problem?

Comment: for me the issue was the flyway and spring version missmatch

Answer (score 57):

Spring-Boot is capable on it's own to do this.
Just add flyway as dependency to your project and spring-boot will pick it up.
Flyway migration will start when the service starts up.

If you already have some tables in the database add:

```
spring.flyway.baselineOnMigrate = true
```

in your property file to keep flyway calm when it discovers that some tables already exist. ;-)

Flyway should pick up your datasource. If you need for example another user or something like that for flyway, you can set these properties:

```
spring.flyway.url: jdbc:postgresql://${db.host}/${db.name}
spring.flyway.user: MYUSER
spring.flyway.password: MYPWD
```

(Of course add your values! You can use SPEL to reference other properties)

**Update**

One word of caution: If you use a clustered database you may encounter problems that multiple instances that are started at the same time try to perform the updates at the same time. This is a problem when the table locks don't work, which happened to me using a clustered mariaDB.

Comment: Use
`flyway.baseline-on-migrate=true`

instead. `flyway.initOnMigrate` is deprecated.

Comment: @SergeiLedvanov What are you talking about? The documentation says `flyway.baselineOnMigrate`. https://flywaydb.org/documentation/configfiles

Comment: I assume that the config-property-classes are used there and it is able to cope with snake_case, kebab-case and camelCase

Comment: with spring boot you use spring.flyway.baseline-on-migrate = true

Comment: For spring boot 2.X.X you need to use prefix all flyway properties values with spring in this case spring.flyway.basline-on-migrate

Comment: Use spring.flyway.baselineOnMigrate = true instead. flyway.baseline-on-migrate=true and flyway.initOnMigrate are deprecated.

Answer (score 7):

For any one who want to solve it in java code you can use :

```
fly.setBaselineOnMigrate(true);
```

---

#### Edit(22-09-2020)

another solution also is :

```
spring:
  flyway:
    baselineOnMigrate: true
    validateOnMigrate: false
```