# Spring Boot test context not loading: Flyway and Spring Boot Data/Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

While running default Spring Boot unit test:

```
@SpringBootTest
class DemoH2FlywayApplicationTests {
    @Test
    void contextLoads() {
    }
}
```

I am getting this error:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'flyway' defined in class path resource
```

I am running Spring Boot 2.6.2, using Flyway and H2, and these dependencies:

```
spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc
spring-boot-starter-data-jpa
spring-boot-starter-web
flyway-core
spring-boot-devtools
h2
lombok
spring-boot-starter-test
```

Here is the demo project: https://github.com/filip194/demo-h2-flyway/.

I am not sure, nor expert, but maybe there is some correlation with Hibernate that I can not understand. I have tried to create test resources folder with application.properties for H2, the same as in the main resources, but nothing changes.

Can anybody help?

Comment: when you add flyway dependency its enabled by default, Try adding application.properties file in test resources folder with spring.flyway.enabled=false

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but the case is I need flyway to create data in DB tables for test purposes.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question is explained in more detail [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50681506/10821440).

There is an error in the following line in the application.properties file.

```
spring.flyway.baseline-on-migrate=true
spring.flyway.validate-on-migrate: false
```

In the second line you should write = instead of :

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I have fixed this typo but nothing changed. I've also taken a look at the link you provided, changed the properties as it is suggested, also added the props for #spring.flyway.url #spring.flyway.user: user and #spring.flyway.password. Didn't help, the same error occurs again.

One interesting thing to note (I am running this test in IntelliJ), when I run this test in debug mode or in coverage mode, it passes.

Comment: `Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Unresolvable class definition; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/intellij/rt/coverage/data/TestDiscoveryProjectData

Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/intellij/rt/coverage/data/TestDiscoveryProjectData

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.intellij.rt.coverage.data.TestDiscoveryProjectData`

Might be the problem with IntelliJ...

Answer (score 0):

I launched your project in Intellij IDEA 2019.3.3 (Java 14) and Maven terminal. The test was completed successfully and the context was created.

Try running your project using the Maven terminal: `mvn clean istall`. Install it in your OS if maven is missing.

If everything is successful, then the problem is probably in the Intellij IDEA

Comment: Thanks for your answer, that's what I was suspecting. Finally, I got a chance to run this test on my peer's computer and it passed with flying colors, so there is something wrong with IntelliJ on my end. Will do as you said.